# Can I iterate a map from a desired key?

Tags: c++

I have map. I need to iterate it not from the beginning, but from the desired key.
I tried it as;

```
  int candidate_s;
  map<int, vector<int> >::iterator map;
  for(map = a_list.begin()+candidate_s; map! = a_list.end(); map++){
      cout<<map->first<<"= ";
      for(vector<int>::iterator vec=map->second.begin(); vec!=map->second.end(); vec++){
          cout<<*vec<<" ";               
      }
  cout<<endl;
  }
```

and I got the following error message:

```
D:\c_mess\merging\src\main.cpp no match for 'operator+' in '(+a_list)->std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin [with _Key = int, _Tp = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >]() + candidate_s'
```

Please help me to rectify this.

Comment: std::map does not have random-access iterators, you cannot add a number to an iterator. What is `candidate_s` supposed to be? Also, please format a code to make it a bit more readable (with spaces).

Comment: @ Kerrek>> sorry for not readability. candidate_s is an interger value. also i can say, it is my desired key of the map. i want to iterate my map starting from that.(not from the begining)

Comment: @Giro: It is hard to imagine how you could _efficiently_ have come by that integer, and almost surely there are better ways of obtaining the iterator. That said, though, you can use `std::advance(it, n);` to advance an iterator.

Comment: thank for the comments. but, i need to iterate it continiously from my desired iterator position. i guess advance(it,n) cant do so as it is random access.

Comment: No, `advance` _always_ works (apart from for non-repeatable iterators). Internally it does magic to use the most efficient method available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that `candidate_s` is of the type of the `std::map`'s key:

```
std::map<int, vector<int> >::const_iterator startIt = a_list.find(candidate_s);
for(; startIt != a_list.end(); ++startIt) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) to get an iterator to a specific key.

If candidate_s is supposed to be an index why not use a presized vector instead? You would have faster look-up times then. However, the vector based solution may not be applicable if your integer keys are sparse / have a wide range of values.